# Removing space/line break between specific parts of a string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, bbcode

I'm trying to make it so a user can add a table into their posts, the problem i'm running into, in another function i'm using `nl2br` to make it so it automatically add line breaks. Though, how tables work, all the line breaks will go above it causing massive amounts of space. I supplied an image below for you to be able to see what I mean. I tried using `\r\n` or `\n`, but I feel like i'm either using it wrong or it doesn't work in this situation.

```
function markupDoc($post){
    //tables
    while(($post2 = preg_replace("/\[td]((?:(?!\[td\]).)+?)\[\/td\]/s", '<td>\\1</td>', $post)) !== $post){
        $post=$post2;
    }
    while(($post2 = preg_replace("/\[tr]((?:(?!\[tr\]).)+?)\[\/tr\]/s", "<tr>\\1</tr>", $post)) !== $post){
        $post=$post2;
    }
    while(($post2 = preg_replace("/\[thead]((?:(?!\[thead\]).)+?)\[\/thead\]/s", '<thead>\\1</thead>', $post)) !== $post){
        $post=$post2;
    }
    while(($post2 = preg_replace("/\[table]((?:(?!\[table\]).)+?)\[\/table\]/s", '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">\\1</table>', $post)) !== $post){
        $post=$post2;
    }   
    return $post;
}
```

String i'm submitting:

```
going to
[table]
    [thead]
        [td]test[/td]
        [td]test[/td]
        [td]moo[/td]
        [td]a[/td]
    [/thead]
    [tr]
        [td]test[/td]
        [td]moo[/td]
    [/tr]
    [tr]
        [td]test[/td]
        [td]test[/td]
        [td]moo[/td]
        [td]a[/td]
    [/tr]
[/table]
```

[image: See the extra space]

Comment: Can you post the actual raw output instead of an image?

Comment: It's returning `<br>` tags above the table because it's not on one line (the string I submitted and it's using `nl2br`). I added the string i'm using though. My developer site i'm using to to test is right here: http://beta.projectdonut.me/docs/v/1385253660-documentation_Demo/updated if anyone would like to view how the page renders it.

Comment: Are you wanting the `<br />` tags removed? Or all that whitespace?

Comment: In between the `[table]`, I want it to be removed. You can see how it's adding the `<br>` tags above the rendered table because that's how tables work and because my string was multi-lines.

Comment: It's adding `<br />` tags after every line of the table.

Comment: Yes, i'm wondering how do I remove it JUST for the table.

Comment: It's likely your function that's causing this issue using `nl2br`, Can you provide that?

Comment: `nl2br(markupDoc($string))` it's as simple as that. nl2br is a PHP function.

Answer (score 0):

Add another function which will take care of different parts of your post. Since the part between `[table]` and `[\table]` clearly differs from the rest you should do something like:

```
function parsePost($post)
{
    $table_start = mb_strpos($post, '[table]');
    $table_end = mb_strpos($post, '[/table]', $table_start);
    $table_end += mb_strlen('[/table]');

    $output = nl2br(mb_substr($post, 0, $table_start));
    $output .= markupDoc(mb_substr($post, $table_start, $table_end - $table_start));
    $output .= nl2br(mb_substr($post, $table_end));
    return $output;
}
```

Test code: http://ideone.com/sfRn33

Comment: That removed some of the extra space, but not all of it.

Comment: I forgot to say: and would this even support multiple tables being in one string?

Comment: Which spaces did it not remove? No it won't support multiple tables, but don't expect us to write your code for you :) You have the recipe, now you can follow it (hint: by putting the code above in a loop).

Comment: I planned to do so. It removed about 10% of the spaces.

Comment: Perhaps you should also wrap the `$output` parts outside the table in a `trim()` function.

Comment: I don't see any extra spaces now, it works as expected: [http://ideone.com/sfRn33](http://ideone.com/sfRn33).